# Streaming mouse position from one computer to another

Tags: java, sockets, events, tcp

I would like to write a application in form of a VNC on java.

At first I try to stream my mouse-position but I just learned some Java in school.

My code:

```
private Maus mouse;

static int cX;
static int cY;

public TestMaus() {
    mouse = new Maus();
     }

public void main() throws Exception {

    String sentence;
    String modifiedSentence;
    BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("", 6789);

    while(true)
    {
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        sentence = String.valueOf(mouse.posX + "I" + mouse.posY);
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
        modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
        clientSocket.close();
    }        
}

public int posX, posY;

public Maus(){     

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseMoved(final MouseEvent e) {
            posX = e.getX();
            posY = e.getY();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you have to add the mouse motion listener to some gui window in order for it to receive mouse events. as it stands you are attempting to add it to an instanceof "Maus" which isn't a gui control

Comment: The connection between your question title and comments isn't quite clear. Also, you have "while(true)"...that's an infinite loop. Your code will certainly crash at some point...or worse, it won't crash at all, but rather just go unresponsive.